# Why harfbuzz shape 2 single char into one glyph?

Tags: glyph, skia, harfbuzz

i'm new to both skia and harfbuzz, my project rely on skia to render text(Skia rely on harfbuzz to shape text.).

So, if i try to render text "ff" or "fl" or "fi"(or maybe some other combinations idk.), instead of render 2 "f", skia will render one glyph which composed of 2 chars("ff" or "fl" or "fi"), it will become much more obvious if i set text letter space property.

By following breakpoints, i tracked and found this all result from shaping result of harfbuzz. Harfbuzz will give out 1 glyph if the text is "ff" or "fl" or "fi".

It seems by making some configs of harfbuzz, i can avoid this, but idk how, please give me some hints.

PS:Shape result will be different if i use different font file, so this is also related to font file i used to shape.

Answer (score 1):

What you are observing is the result of ligature glyph substitutions that occur during text layout.

Harfbuzz is performing advanced text layout using OpenType Layout features in a font. OpenType features are a mechanism for enabling different typographic capabilities that are supported in the font.

Some features are required for correct display of a script. For example, certain features are used to trigger word-contextual forms in Arabic script, or to trigger positioning of vowel marks in Bangla script or diacritic marks in Latin script. These are mandatory for correct display of these scripts.

Other features trigger optional typographic capabilities of a font—they're not essential for correct display of the script, but may be desired for high quality typography. Small caps or superscript forms are two examples of optional features. Many optional features are should not be used in applications by default. For instance, small caps should only be used when the content author explicitly wants them.

But in OpenType some optional features are recommended for use by default since they are intended to provide good quality typography for any body text. One such feature is "Standard Ligatures".

Your specific cases, "ff", "fi", etc., are considered standard ligatures. In any publication that has high quality typography, these will always be used in body text. Because the OpenType spec recommends that Standard Ligatures be applied by default, that's exactly what Harfbuzz is doing.

You can read the [Harfbuzz documentation](https://harfbuzz.github.io/shaping-opentype-features.html) to find out more able how to enable or disable OpenType features. And you can find descriptions of all OpenType features in the [OpenType Layout Tag Registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/ttoreg) (part of the OpenType spec).

OpenType features use data contained directly in the fonts. Harfbuzz will enable the Standard Ligatures feature by default, but not all fonts necessarily have data that pertains to that feature. That's why you see the behaviour with some fonts but not others.

When a font does support features, the font data describe glyph-level actions to be performed. Harfbuzz (or any OpenType layout engine) will read the data and they perform the described actions. There are several types of actions that can be performed. One is a ligature substution—that is, substitute a sequence of glyphs with a single glyph, the *ligature* glyph. Ligature substitution actions could be used in fonts for a variety of purposes. Forming a "ff" ligature is one example. But a font might also substitute the default glyphs for a base letter and following combining mark with a single glyph that incorporates the base letter and the mark with the precise positioning of the mark for that combination. And that's something that would be essential for correct display of the script, but something that should be optional.

Thus, it would be a bad idea to disable all ligature substitutions. That's why OpenType has features as a trigger/control mechanism: features are organized around distinct typographic results, not the specific glyph-level actions used to achieve those results. So, you could disable a feature like Standard Ligatures without blocking ligature substitution actions that get used by the font for other typographic purposes.

Comment: Excellent answer, but a small comment: "In any publication that has high quality typography, these [ligatures] will always be used in body text." This is not true for every language. For example, in German these ligatures are not usually used (maybe because the rules when a ligature is allowed and when not, are very complicated. It's not as trivial as for English where you can always use them).

Comment: Fair enough. Let me provide a little more detail: In an OpenType font, glyph actions are described in "lookup" tables, and the actions get triggered by "features". The above ligatures are triggered by a "Discretionary Ligatures" feature that is applied by default. But data is organized by "language systems". So, the font developer can add actions to form ligatures for some language, but not have the same actions for other languages. The feature is always applied by default in either case, but the actual glyph actions can be different.